# How to enforce that two (PK same FK) columns from two different tables are disjoint

Tags: postgresql, create-table

Consider the following example

- Vehicle is my superclass
- Bike and Car are my subclasses

```
CREATE TABLE Vehicle (

    Vehicle_id        INT   PRIMARY KEY
    ...

);

CREATE TABLE Bike (

    Vehicle_id       INT   PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Vehicle(Vehicle_id)
    ...

);

CREATE TABLE Car (

    Vehicle_id       INT   PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Vehicle(Vehicle_id)
    ...

);
```

- Vehicle doesn't have to be a Bike or a Car but it can't be both a Bike and a Car
- I've been trying something like this (How do I reference Bike in `??`)

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY Car
   ADD CONSTRAINT not_in_bike CHECK (??)
```

- Alternatively, can I do something like this

```
ALTER TABLE Car AND Bike
    ADD CONSTRAINT Car_or_Bike CHECK (Car.Vehicle_id <> Bike.Vehicle_id)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. Store all entities in a single table and use a column (`type` or so) to determine which type a certain row is.
2. Use the layout you have now, but add a column `type` to all three tables. Add that column to the primary key or create a unique constraint on `(vehicle_id, type)`.

   Define the foreign keys to include `type` and make sure they have the correct value using a `CHECK` constraint:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE bike ADD FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id, vehicle_type) REFERENCES vehicle;

   ALTER TABLE bike ADD CHECK (vehicle_type = 'bike');
   ```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. 

"Define the foreign keys to include type and make sure they have the correct value using a CHECK constraint."

Could you help me on this part? I'm new to SQL ):

Comment: I have added sample SQL statements.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is there a way I can do this without adding another column. Like using a constraint or trigger?

Comment: I cannot think of another good way. Triggers can of course be used, but unless you use `SERIALIZABLE` transaction Isolation, they are always subject to race conditions.

Comment: If it's not too much trouble (and honestly if it is too much trouble, don't bother), would you be able to show me such a solution with Triggers?

Comment: I am too lazy to write the code for you. It would be a simple function with `IF EXISTS (SELECT ...) THEN RAISE EXCEPTION '...'; END IF;`.

Comment: Right ok. Thank you so much for your time!